# Uniformly convergent & point convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let ${({f_n})_n}$ is a sequence that ${f_n}(x)=tan^{-1}(nx), x\in [0,\infty)$.

Prove for every $[a,b]$ that $a>0$ is Uniformly convergent and on $[0,b]$ just point wise convergent.

Comment: The function $f_n$ doesn't depend on $n$?

Comment: sorry i mistake

Comment: What is the pointwise limit? Is it continuous on $[0,b]$? For the first part, note $\arctan y$ increases to $\pi/2$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(f_n)$ is point-wise convergent to the function $f$ defined by

$$f(0)=0\quad;\quad f(x)=\frac\pi2,\;\forall x>0$$
and since $f$ isn't continuous whereas the functions $f_n$ are continuous so the convergence isn't uniform on $[0,\infty)$